# Deleting dynamically allocated array members in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

Lets say I have an array of structs and I want to delete an entry that has a struct with an entry matching some criteria.

This array is dynamically allocated with malloc, I keep the element count in a separate variable.

How do I go about deleting the entry?

I'm thinking of

```
for (i = pos; i < arr_len; i++) {
  arr[i] = arr[i+1];
}
arr_len--;
```

But this leaves the same amount of memory for the array while I actually need less and an orphan (sort of) last entry.

Is issuing a realloc in such situation an accepted practice? Would realloc do memcpy in this case? (shortening the allocated memory by one block).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`realloc` is ok ... but keep reading :)

`realloc` will not move parts of the memory; it may move the whole block. So you need to copy the data before changing the allocated size.

To move the data, `memmove` (not `memcpy`) is a good option: it works for memory areas that belong to the same object. Pay attention to not go over your array limits, though; like you do in your code.

```
for (i = pos; i < arr_len; i++) {
  arr[i] = arr[i+1];
}
```

The `arr[i] = arr[i + 1];` will try to access one past the allowed size. You need

```
for (i = pos + 1; i < arr_len; i++) {
  arr[i - 1] = arr[i];
}
```

---

There is somewhat of an overhead when calling `realloc`. If your structs are not large and/or they live only for a short while, consider keeping both an element count and allocated count and only realloc to enlarge (when `(element_count + 1) > (allocated_count)`).

---

If the struct is large, also consider a different data structure (linked list perhaps).

Comment: Thanks for the catch on last element access. I've wrote this specific case on paper but still managed to miss it when briefly forgetting that arrays are indexed from 0!

Answer (score 1):

Calling realloc to shrink the allocated memory would not necessarily be a bad idea.

However, you might have to reconsider the data structure you are using. It looks like a linked list would make it much easier to manage memory and make the delete operation much faster since it doesn't require shifting elements.

Answer (score 0):

Using realloc would be appropriate here.  It wouldn't do a memcpy -- that's only necessary when the realloc size is larger and there's no room to expand.